# Unable to click button which is inside iframe and table in Selenium webDriver with c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#-4.0, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to c# and I am working with Selenium chrome webdriver in c#. I am trying to click button which inside table. I am not able to identify and click button.The hierarchy of button is (Page > PopOver > PopOverFrame > Table1 > Table2 > Button to click )

Any help with this would be much appreciated thank you.

my code is :

```
          */
        // Closing old tab, keeping control in new tab and trying to perform click operation
        var currentWindow = BaseTest.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        var availableWindows = new List<string>(BaseTest.Driver.WindowHandles);

        foreach (string mywindows in availableWindows)
            {

            if (mywindows != currentWindow)
                {
                Driver.SwitchTo().Window(mywindows).Close();
                }
            else
                {
                Driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentWindow);

                // performing click action on RUN REPORT button

                IWebElement popOver = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popOver"));
                IWebElement popOverFrame = popOver.FindElement(By.Id("popOverFrame"))
                IWebElement table1 = popOverFrame.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form1']/table"));
                IWebElement Table2 = table1.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tblReport']"));
                Table2.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_btnPrint")).Click();
                }
            }
```

[Please refer to attached screenshot of  what html page looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD82d.png)

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ><title>

 <div id="divReportHeader">
        <span id="contentPlaceholder_lblReportDescHeader" class="reportHeader">Description</span>
        
        <br>
  <span id="contentPlaceholder_lblReportDescription">Offer</span>
  
 </div>
 <table>
  <tbody><tr>
   <td style="vertical-align: top;">
    <div style="margin: 2px; padding: 8px;">
     <table width="1000px" style="border-spacing: 0; padding: 0" id="tblReport">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><div id="contentPlaceholder_generalInformation" class="reportHeader">Information</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <span id="contentPlaceholder_lblRptInfo">
                                    This report may require more information. Click "Run Report" to view the report inline.
        </span>
        <br>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

      </tr>
                        <tr>
                            
                        </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <span id="contentPlaceholder_lblfrom">abc </span>        
                                
        <select name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$ddlfromYear" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentPlaceholder$ddlfromYear\',\'\')', 0)" id="contentPlaceholder_ddlfromYear">

</select>
               
        <span id="contentPlaceholder_lblFilter5" style="display: block; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 4px;">Additional columns to be included:<br>Due to potential page size limitations, additional custom columns should only be selected when intending to view inline or export as Excel.</span>
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$btnSelectAll" value="Select All" id="contentPlaceholder_btnSelectAll" class="roundedButton">
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$btnDeselectAll" value="Deselect All" id="contentPlaceholder_btnDeselectAll" class="roundedButton" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <table id="chkList2" class="correctCheckboxes">
 <tbody><tr>hkList2_0" value="Select"><label for="chkList2_0">Help</label></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
        
       
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
                                <br>
        <div id="contentPlaceholder_parameterNotes" class="reportHeader">
          Notes
        </div>
                                <br>
                                <span id="contentPlaceholder_txtParameterNotes">None</span>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        
        
        
        
        
        

       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        
        <input type="submit" name="ctl00$contentPlaceholder$btnPrint" value="RUN REPORT" onclick="disable('contentPlaceholder_btnPrint');__doPostBack('ctl00$contentPlaceholder$btnPrint','');" id="contentPlaceholder_btnPrint" class="roundedButton" style="width:130px;">
        
                                
        
        
        
        
        
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody></table>
   </div></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody></table>
 
 

 
 <iframe id="ifrmDownload" style="display: none;"></iframe>
 <iframe id="ifrmStatus" src="statuscheck.aspx" style="display: none;"></iframe>

  </form>
 
</body></html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you just copied the html code instead of the photo.

Comment: Hi Hashim77, I have added html code. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//remove this line IWebElement popOver = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popOver"));
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
IWebElement popOverFrame = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("popOverFrame"))
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(popOverFrame);
//remove this line IWebElement table1 = popOverFrame.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form1']/table"));
IWebElement Table2 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tblReport']"));
Table2.FindElement(By.Id("contentPlaceholder_btnPrint")).Click();
```

Comment: The reason for the answer is that, most pages with iframes need to be switched to in order to interact with. So you would first switch to default content and then whatever the first iframe is in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you Hashim that worked for me . Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(iframeXpath)));
```

And once the operations are completed inside iFrame, switch back to default content.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```